# Passing multiple parameters to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm using SQL Server 2012, and I have a stored procedure with more than 25 parameters, which I need to call from C#. In my experience, having this many parameters can cause headaches when things go wrong, trying to identify which parameter is wrong/missing/whatever.

I've used Oracle in the past, which has the concept of user Defined Types, so it is possible to create a Type, which contains the 25 parameters, and pass this in instead. Now we have just one parameter.

What's the equivalent of this in SQL Server? I've read about Table Value parameters, and it seems obvious that this is what I should use, but I'm wondering if this is overkill for what would only ever have one row (i.e. one set of parameters). Every example I've seen describes how to use these to pass in multiple rows, so I'm wondering if there's a simpler way that I've missed.

Comment: How is this going to help you identity which parameter is causing failure?

Comment: Well, the simplest example is "Expected 25 parameters, only received 24". You then have a search on your hands. Or maybe you swapped an int and a varchar by mistake, and you have some kind of Invalid Type error, but no indication where. With UDTs, you can't make these mistakes (or you can, but you find out at compile time). I still have fond memories of the C# error I saw once - "No overload for method CreateCustomer takes 44 parameters".

Comment: If you used a Table Value Parameter and you always passed "one row" in the TVP, then I would agree--that is overkill.  As @Dave.Gugg suggests, it won't help you identify a missing/invalid param anyway. If I was in your shoes (and using C#), I'd have a single method/function in a data layer that calls the SQL SP.  Depending on the app design, the C# method would accept an object with the 25 properties or one input param for each of the SP input params. Within that C# method, verify the presence and validity of all the 25 properties/params.